# How to transform documents to key-value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Well, I have documents with this strcuture:

```
{
    "x" : "X1",
    "y" : 10
},
{
    "x" : "X2",
    "y" : 22
},
{
    "x" : "...",
    "y" : 42
}
```

So, how I can convert all results to:

```
{
    "X1" : 10,
    "X2" : 22,
    "X3" : 42
}
```

I trying with `$arrayToObject` and `$map`, but this dont work

Thanks!

> This collection have arround 50 millions docs.

Comment: You could not ask MongoDB to do that. And why would you want 50 million keys in a single object anyway? If you have that many then logically there would be some other grouping to consider. So the question does not really make any sense.

Comment: Well, because the value is "hits" or "counter". So, only get arround 20 keys :D
Example: `{ "ABC" : 20847, "XYZ" : 23455}`

Comment: Try to take the time to explain in your question. It sounds like you mean `{ "x": "X1", "y": 10 }, { "x": "X1", "y": 20 }` comes out as `{ "X1": 30 }` by that statement in comment when prompted, but there is nothing in your question that says anything like that. Nothing about "hits" or a "counter" and absolutely nothing about accumulating per key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your collection is small enough so that an output of following operation won't exceed [16MB BSON limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/index.html), you can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            docs: {
                $push: {
                    k: "$x",
                    v: "$y"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: "$docs"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) expects objects having two properties `k` and `v`. To promote that object to a root level you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) operator.

Comment: @OlafErlandsen but the thing is you need all of them to be a part of output of this operation or you can apply any filtering before merging into one document ?

Comment: need all, because it calculate the number of visits by date(key) and hits(value)

Comment: @OlafErlandsen so the problem is that you can't get more than 16MB as a single document in MongoDB. You can check if you're getting an error using this query

Comment: no, i dont have this error, I'm allow to using disk ;)